# Laravel - Querying Eloquent 3 table with conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i've been searching everywhere including stackoverflow but still cannot get an answer for my case.

so i've 3 models User,Todo,and TodoItem.

i'm trying to let the user search a todolist and searching based on the todo title or description or the todoitem description.

> here is my current code

```php
private function searchTodos(){
        return ModelsTodo::
        where('creator',Auth::user()->id)
        ->with('TodoItem',
            function($q) {
                    $q->where('description','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%');
            })
        ->where(function($q){
            $q->where('title','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%');
        })
        ->latest()
        ->paginate($this->perPage);
    }
```

this can already searching for the todo title and description, but still cannot searching for the todoitem description.

when i try to search for the todoitem description it doesn't found anything.

this is my models relationship

> User.php

```php
public function Todos(){
    return $this->hasMany(Todo::class,'creator');
}
```

> Todo.php

```php
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'creator');
}
public function TodoItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TodoItem');
}
```

> TodoItem.php

```php
public function Todo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Todo');
}
```

is there anyway to achieve this using eloquent?

i'm relatively new to multiple table relationship using eloquent so i'm very confused how to do this using eloquent.

Comment: You could enable query log to get an idea about where you are going wrong. That said, I thought the `with` method required an array if you wanted to apply constraints. That is: `with(['TodoItem' => function($q) ...])` Maybe give this a go? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: nope it's not working either way. the todoitem still won't included in the search

Comment: Change `with` into `whereHas`.

Comment: still doesn't work using whereHas

Comment: To be honest, it feels kinda disrespectful that people try to help you and you continue to just say "not working" there can be a little more effort to help people, this is a free service with an insanely high level of effort of skill compared to it is free, then at least acknowledge peoples time a little more. So going forward describe in dept why the changes does not work, what you tryed etc. Not working is simply to generic for anything constructive to be done about it.

Comment: hi, sorry if you think i'm disrespectfull. thankyou for everyone for the help.

Comment: Dont worry it was just a reminder :) have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems, you search logic seems wrong for what i would expect for such a search feature. You are doing the following like search.

```
todoItem.description like %search% and (title like %search% or description like %search%)
```

This requires todoItem to have same description as title or description, which seem unlikely?

Secondly with is not a query condition but a filtering aproach to after the model has been found. While I'm not certain that syntax is even correct. You should use `whereHas()` instead. I believe the following approach would work.

```
ModelsTodo::where('creator',Auth::user()->id)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas(
            'TodoItem',
            function($q) {
                $q->where('description','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%');
            }
        )->orWhere(function($q) {
            $q->where('title','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%');
            })
        })
    ->latest()
    ->paginate($this->perPage);
```

This makes your logic into this condition

```
(todoItem.description like %search% or (title like %search% or description like %search%))
```

**Style and ending notes**

- Don't name your relationships in pascal case, that should be camel case.
- Be consistent with styles there is a lot of (){ instead of () {
- Indention is not consistent

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help!! and sorry if you think i'm disrespectfull. this really works like what i expected. and thankyou so much for the suggestions. abou the identation it's because i still learning how to write a good markdown, i try to copy paste my code on markdown but its all got messed up